# Using log4j in an ear under weblogic 12c

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, ejb, weblogic, slf4j

I'm trying to configure log4j with slf4j to run under weblogic and manage the logs of an ear app with a web module and an ejb. While the web module prints the messages in the log file I configured, the ejb does not. It's like the ejb does not see the configuration file and does not initialize log4j.

The ear has this structure:

```
--APP-INF
  --LIB
     --log4j-1.2.17.jar
     --slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
     --slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
  --classes
    --log4j.xml
--META-INF
EJB.JAR
WEB.WAR
```

And the configuration file (log4j.xml) in the APP-INF/classes folder of the ear:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

        <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
            </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1000KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="/shared_ISILON_WLS/AppLogs/project/project.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileSQL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1000KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="/shared_ISILON_WLS/AppLogs/project/project_SQL.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="es.project">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </logger>
        <logger name="org.primefaces">
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </logger>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.persistence">
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="fileSQL" />       
        </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

From the documentation and other stackoverflow questions I checked, the configuration file has to be read from the ejb module right?
I've also checked that there is no other configuration file inside the modules.
It's there anything more to configure for the ejb module to see the configuration file?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have exactly same issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve this simply adding `<wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>com.oracle.foo</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>` in the ejb weblogic.xml. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You will have to ensure that log4j.xml file is available in classpath for the EJB jar. You can look at the manifest of the jar to make sure it's there. Once it is present in the classpath, it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: I have added to manifest.mf of the ejb jar:  `Class-Path: APP-INF/classes/log4j.xml` but without any result. It's there anyway to debug what it's happening with log4j in the ejb?

Answer (score 0):

Adding log4j.xml file in app.ear/APP-INF/classes directory worked for me. Are you getting system out? May be there is another log4j.xml on the classpath that is defining the logger for org.hiberante and writing log somewhere else...